# Colab markdown cell creates an unwanted link

Tags: html, google-colaboratory

I'm new to Colab and faced a problem that didn't exist when I used Jupyter Notebook.

When I leave a date in a markdown cell like

```
Last edited: 2020/9/22
```

What's created is a text with a strange unwanted hyperlink like

Last edited: 2020[/9/22](https://???)

I tried to google 'colab slash' to see if I triggered an internal command, but it was a weak keyword and I couldn't find anything.

Could someone point out what I triggered and how to avoid it? I just wish to have a plain date like

Last edited: 2020/9/22

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You can add `<wbr>` to avoid auto-linking. For example

```
Last edited: 2020/9/<wbr>22
```

It will be shown correctly without hyperlink.

Comment: Thank you. Could you perhaps point out that's causing the auto-link though?

Comment: This doesn't work if the text is in a code block